# Anaconda activation

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda (with PATH), created new environment and now I want to activate it using this command:

> conda activate myenv

After that I type this command I didn't get any information but I assume it is normal.
When I use command

> python

I'm getting this information:

> Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the
>   environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To
>   activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation

All instructions that I use:

> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>conda activate myenv
>
> (myenv) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>pytohn Nazwa 'pytohn' nie jest
>   rozpoznawana jako polecenie wewnętrzne lub zewnętrzne, program
>   wykonywalny lub plik wsadowy.
>
> (myenv) C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3>python Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr 24
>   2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Ana conda, Inc. on
>   win32
>
> Warning: This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the
>   environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To
>   activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation
>
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

I did something wrong during activation? How I can check if conda is activated?